# JSP и "динамическая" ссылка

Tags: jsp, java

Добрый день, проблема следующая. 
На страницу из БД подтягивается таблица с некоторыми значениями. Выводятся не все поля таблицы, а только часть. У каждого элемента таблицы есть ID, как сделать так, что бы по клику на ID нас перекидывало на другую страницу (или можно на этой же странице) для вывода всех остальных полей этого объекта? На странице таких объектов может быть очень много..

Тот же вопрос, только короче. Как должна выглядеть ссылка, что бы по клику на нее можно было записать в сессию какие либо параметры?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делать с помощью jstl.

Во первых - логику нужно выносить в сервлеты, и где-то там внутри у Вас будет, что-то такое:

```
List objectList = dataLoader.getList(); // загружаете данные из базы
request.setAttribute("objectList", objectList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

На странице list.jsp, подключаем библиотеку тэгов:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="core" %>
```

и используем примерно так:

```
<core:forEach var="object" items="${requestScope.objectList}">
    <a href="/link?id=${object.id}">some action</a>
</core:forEach>
```

В 2х словах как то так :)

Comment: Спасибо, щас попробую )

Comment: А как потом из такого линка подхватить данные? У меня есть мысли, но кажется что есть решение куда более простое и надежное. Может библиотека есть какая?

Comment: Из линка через

    String id = request.getParameter("id");